# Whats a Mimunah-מימונה?

Tags: minhag, passover, sefirat-ha-omer, chametz-leaven

There is a custom of those of Moroccan decent to make a "Mimunah". What does this custom entail, how did it develop, and what does it have to do with Pesach? A general overview of the Custom would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*See* Ari Enkin, *Mimouna*, Hirhurim - Torah Musings (Apr. 25, 2011) http://torahmusings.com/2011/04/mimouna/

Comment: Please replace the lengthy quotation with a summary per http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/04/guidelines-referring-and-quoting.html